# TLS Callback in Windows

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

Here is the test code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

__declspec(thread) int tls_int = 0;

void NTAPI tls_callback(PVOID, DWORD dwReason, PVOID)   
{
    tls_int = 1;
}

#pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLB")
PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK p_thread_callback = tls_callback;
#pragma data_seg()

int main()
{
    cout<<"main thread tls value = "<<tls_int<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Build with Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)
run result: `main thread tls value = 1`

Build with Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)
run result: `main thread tls value = 0`

It looks like I cannot capture the main thread created when MTd is used.

Why is this the case?

Comment: You voided the warranty by using an undocumented CRT implementation detail.  The "why" is that the .CRT$XL? sections are only used to get TLS initialized when a program links the DLL version of the CRT.  It isn't used with /MT.

Comment: thanks Hans Passant , and how to do the TLS callback with /MT

Comment: You just can't, this is only for the CRT's benefit, it is not part of the language standard.

Comment: @HansPassant while you're technically right, this code is just missing an ingredient. See answer below.

Answer (score 16):

While **Ofek Shilon** is right that the code is missing an ingredient, his answer contains only part of the whole ingredient.

For explanation on how it works you may refer to [this blog](http://www.nynaeve.net/?tag=tls) (assume we are working with VC++ compiler).

For convenience the code is posted below (note both x86 & x64 platforms are supported):

```
#include <windows.h>
  
// Explained in p. 2 below
void NTAPI tls_callback(PVOID DllHandle, DWORD dwReason, PVOID)
{
    if (dwReason == DLL_THREAD_ATTACH)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"DLL_THREAD_ATTACH", L"DLL_THREAD_ATTACH", 0);
    }
  
    if (dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", L"DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH", 0);
    }
}
  
#ifdef _WIN64
     #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_used")  // See p. 1 below
     #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:tls_callback_func")  // See p. 3 below
#else
     #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:__tls_used")  // See p. 1 below
     #pragma comment (linker, "/INCLUDE:_tls_callback_func")  // See p. 3 below
#endif
  
// Explained in p. 3 below
#ifdef _WIN64
    #pragma const_seg(".CRT$XLF")
    EXTERN_C const
#else
    #pragma data_seg(".CRT$XLF")
    EXTERN_C
#endif
PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK tls_callback_func = tls_callback;
#ifdef _WIN64
    #pragma const_seg()
#else
    #pragma data_seg()
#endif //_WIN64
  
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(CONST LPVOID lpParam) 
{
    ExitThread(0);
}
  
int main(void)
{
    MessageBox(0, L"hello from main", L"main", 0);
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ThreadProc, 0, 0, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Definitely some explanations are required so let us take a look on what's going on in the code.

1. If we want to use TLS callbacks then we are to tell the compiler about it explicitly. It is done with the including of the variable `_tls_used` which has a pointer to the callback array (null-terminated). For the type of this variable you may consult `tlssup.c` in CRT source code coming along with Visual Studio:

- For VS 12.0 by default it lies here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\`
- For VS 14.0 by default it lies here: `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\`

It is defined in the following way:

```
#ifdef _WIN64

_CRTALLOC(".rdata$T") const IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY64 _tls_used =
{
        (ULONGLONG) &_tls_start,        // start of tls data
        (ULONGLONG) &_tls_end,          // end of tls data
        (ULONGLONG) &_tls_index,        // address of tls_index
        (ULONGLONG) (&__xl_a+1),        // pointer to call back array
        (ULONG) 0,                      // size of tls zero fill
        (ULONG) 0                       // characteristics
};

#else  /* _WIN64 */

_CRTALLOC(".rdata$T")
const IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY _tls_used =
{
        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_start, // start of tls data
        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_end,   // end of tls data
        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) &_tls_index, // address of tls_index
        (ULONG)(ULONG_PTR) (&__xl_a+1), // pointer to call back array
        (ULONG) 0,                      // size of tls zero fill
        (ULONG) 0                       // characteristics
};
```

This code initializes values for `IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY(64)` structure which is pointed to by the TLS directory entry. And pointer to call back array is one of its fields. This array is traversed by the OS loader and pointed functions are being called until null pointer is met.

*For info about directories in PE file consult [this link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx) and search for a description of `IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY DataDirectory[IMAGE_NUMBEROF_DIRECTORY_ENTRIES]`.*

*x86 note: as you can see, the same name `_tls_used` is met in `tlssup.c` for both x86 & x64 platforms, but additional `_` is added when including this name for x86 build. It's not a typo but linker feature, so effectively naming `__tls_used` is taken.*

2. Now we are at the point of creating our callback. Its type can be obtained from the definition of `IMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY(64)` which can be found in `winnt.h`, there is a field

for x64:

```
ULONGLONG AddressOfCallBacks;  // PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK *;
```

and for x86:

```
DWORD   AddressOfCallBacks;  // PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK *
```

The type of callbacks is defined as follows (also from `winnt.h`):

```
typedef VOID
(NTAPI *PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK) (PVOID DllHandle, DWORD Reason, PVOID Reserved);
```

It is the same as for `DllMain` and it can handle the same set of events: process\thread attach\detach.

3. It is time to register callback.
   First of all take a look at the code from `tlssup.c`:

Sections allocated in it:

```
_CRTALLOC(".CRT$XLA") PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK __xl_a = 0;

/* NULL terminator for TLS callback array.  This symbol, __xl_z, is never
 * actually referenced anywhere, but it must remain.  The OS loader code
 * walks the TLS callback array until it finds a NULL pointer, so this makes
 * sure the array is properly terminated.
 */

_CRTALLOC(".CRT$XLZ") PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK __xl_z = 0;
```

It is very important to know what is special in `$` when naming PE section, so the quote from the article named ["Compiler and linker support for implicit TLS"](http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=183):

> Non-header data in a PE image is placed into one or more sections,
> which are regions of memory with a common set of attributes (such as
> page protection). The `__declspec(allocate(“section-name”))` keyword
> (CL-specific) tells the compiler that a particular variable is to be
> placed in a specific section in the final executable. The compiler
> additionally has support for concatenating similarly-named sections
> into one larger section. This support is activated by prefixing a
> section name with a `$` character followed by any other text. The
> compiler concatenates the resulting section with the section of the
> same name, truncated at the `$` character (inclusive).
>
> The compiler alphabetically orders individual sections when
> concatenating them (due to the usage of the $ character in the section
> name). This means that in-memory (in the final executable image), a
> variable in the `“.CRT$XLB”` section will be after a variable in the
> `“.CRT$XLA”` section but before a variable in `“.CRT$XLZ”` section. The C
> runtime uses this quirk of the compiler to create an array of null
> terminated function pointers to TLS callbacks (with the pointer stored
> in the `“.CRT$XLZ”` section being the null terminator). Thus, in order
> to ensure that the declared function pointer resides within the
> confines of the TLS callback array being referenced by `_tls_used`, it
> is necessary place in a section of the form `“.CRT$XLx“`.

There may be actually 2+ callbacks (we will actually use only one) and we may want to call them in order, now we know how. Just place these callbacks in sections named in alphabetical order.

`EXTERN_C` is added to forbid C++-style name mangling and use a C-style one.

`const` and `const_seg` are used for x64 version of the code because otherwise it fails to work, I don't know exact reason for this, the guess may be that CRT sections' access rights are different for x86 & x64 platforms.

And finally we are to include name of the callback function for linker to know it is to be added to the TLS call back array. For note about additional `_` for x64 build see the end of p.1 above.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Explanations elsewhere can disappear due to link rot.

Comment: Note also that relying on compiler internals means that it may stop working when you upgrade to a newer version of the compiler.

Comment: Added the explanation, but some details are still missing: 1) `const_seg` for x64 instead of `data_seg`; 2) additional `_` in naming for x86. Can whoever enlighten me on these peculiarities?

Comment: As for point 1), VC2022 (19.39) warns when using `data_seg` on x86_64. `LIBCMT.lib(exe_main.obj) : warning LNK4078: multiple '.CRT' sections found with different attributes (40400040)` [LNK4078](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4078?view=msvc-170) and `LIBCMT.lib(initializers.obj) : warning LNK4254: section '.CRT' (C0000040) merged into '.rdata' (40000040) with different attributes` [LNK4254](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-warning-lnk4254?view=msvc-170).
Can `const_seg` be used on x86 too?

Answer (score 1):

You also must explicitly add the symbol __tls_used. With this your code should work:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/include:__tls_used")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `#pragma comment(linker,"/include:__tls_used")` if you use implicit TLS variable(`__declspec(thread)`).