# Other alternatives to bypass WH_CALLWNDPROC global hook + Dll injection (Ring 3)?

Tags: c++, windows, delphi, winapi, dll-injection

I want know what are the possible solutions to bypass a dll injection made by a rootkit everytime that any process is executed (***where is used a global hook on*** [**`WH_CALLWNDPROC`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks) ***message to detect this***)?

[image]

Based in my case and also in [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/2281/24905), i already know (and tested) of two alternatives that works 100% to bypass this, are they::

**1**. [**`UnhookWindowsHookEx`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-unhookwindowshookex)

**2**. Execute my process via other process, with flag **DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS** using [**`CreateProcess`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), to receive notifications of DLL loading, when this is detected i take the EntryPoint of dll and write something to that, then the dll is unloaded.

---

***3***. Other possible solution could be **TLS** callback like was said on answer linked above, but i don't know how implement (in code) to this purpose of *anti dll injection*. Someone know and could give a code example?

Thank you in advance by any suggestion/or others alternatives to bypass this way of dll injection.

---

**EDITION:**

I think that the 3rd possible solution enumerated above seems deserve
a attention. Then I'm searching by a answer with a code example about this: *"`A process can host a TLS callback, and then it will receive notifications of thread creation. That can intercept thread creation such as what is produced by CreateRemoteThread. If the thread start address is LoadLibrary(), then you have a good indication that someone is about to force-load a DLL.`"* And then block the dll injection.

Comment: Keep in mind `UnhookWindowsHookEx` itself can be detoured and replaced by a hostile injectee, along with most other APIs & user-mode functions.

Comment: What's the question here, how to un-pwn a pwned machine? That's not going to happen.

Comment: @IInspectable, The question is: Someone have other possible solution to bypass this or in negative case, could give a code example about **TLS** callback to protect against dll injetion?

Comment: Consider putting a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), I don't think bumping is giving you your desired outcome.

Comment: if you want example how implement TLS in c++ ask separate question exactly for this or change current

Comment: @RbMm, is done.

Comment: note that tls callbacks called only on create new thread (not including loader working threads in win 10), this not give exactly dll load notification. also dll can be injected without create new thread too (say via apc).general answer about tls implementation - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538159/about-tls-callback-in-windows/36891752#36891752. however can be and more simply

Comment: @RbMm, then how tls callback could be more simply to detect `CreateRmoteThread` or `LoadLibray`?

Comment: tls callback not detect dll load. if you use *c++* runtime - code is next https://pastebin.com/PrYZCQFp

Comment: @RbMm, then **tls** callback not is a efficient solution and not must be recommended. Thank you very much by yours comments :-)

Comment: if you want monitor dll load - you need [`LdrRegisterDllNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/devnotes/ldrregisterdllnotification) but of course callback will be called only if dll will be load normal way (via `LdrLoadDll` ) and anyway what is "inject" - undefined. this is not a clear concept

Comment: @RbMm, *tls* callback can is able to bypass anything made inside **CreateProcess** (made by [`PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-pssetcreateprocessnotifyroutine)) notification routine callback in kernel mode (like a dll injection for example?

Comment: i dont understand question. tls callback called on thread create/exit thread and start /exit process. how this related to call `CreateProcess` ?! . and how this related to kernel mode notify on process create ?

Comment: @RbMm, exists rootkit's that call some routine of dll injection inside `PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx` when they detect process creation, then if I (in ring 3) use a tls callback where is executed a inline hook in `LdrLoadDll` api for example, this will be able to bypass the dll injection of rootkit (since that he used `LdrLoadDll` function to this)?

Comment: @RbMm, for example, see in [**this article**](https://malwaretips.com/threads/developing-your-own-anti-exe-c-device-driver-development.64043/) *PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB* routine. Several rootkit's executes some dll injection inside this callback. I hope that you can understand better now :-)

Comment: [Here](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/40737-inject-dll-from-kernel-mode/) is a code that a rootkit could use to inject dll in kernel mode and call the routine inside *PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB*. This linked code uses `LdrLoadDll`, then i back to my previous question: - `tls callback in ring 3 application executing a inline hook against LdrLoadDl api is able to prevent this type of injection (PsCreateProcessNotifyEx_CB + LdrLoadDll) in kernel mode?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's unnecessary to keep finding different alternatives, instead, use the alternatives you have already found, such as **UnhookWindowsHookEx**. If you want, just try out the TLS callback anyway.

Comment: Based on comments of @RbMm. **tls** callback not is a solution. Seems that only the items **1** and **2** (see in my question above).